# Popup menu when Item in list view is clicked

Tags: android, kotlin, listview, popupmenu

I am stuck trying to figure out how to make a popup menu appear when an Item in a list view is selected. I have attempted to put together various code segments together and a few different methods but this is what I have at the moment.

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.test)


        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)

        var tl = arrayOf("a","a","a","a","a")

        val listview = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.tlist)
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, tl)
        listview.adapter = adapter
        listview.onItemClickListener = object : OnItemClickListener{

            override fun onItemClick(
                parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                view: View?,
                position: Int,
                id: Long
            )

            {

                val listPopupmenu = View(tl+[position])

                val showPopUp = PopupMenu(
                    this,
                    listPopupmenu
                )

                showPopUp.setOnMenuItemClickListener { menuItem ->
                    val id = menuItem.itemId
                    if (id == 0) {
                        textView.text = "Item 0"
                    } else if (id == 1) {
                        textView.text = "Item 1"
                    } else if (id == 2) {
                        textView.text = "Item 2"
                    } else if (id == 3) {
                        textView.text = "Item 3"
                    }
                    false
                }



                showPopUp.menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, 0, "Item 0")
                showPopUp.menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, 1, "Item 1")
                showPopUp.menu.add(Menu.NONE, 2, 2, "Item 2")
                showPopUp.menu.add(Menu.NONE, 3, 3, "Item 3")

                listPopupmenu.setOnClickListener {
                    showPopUp.show()
                }

                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "${textView} was clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }




    }
}
```

I am trying to make it so that when you select an item on the list, it has a drop down window with options. Then when you select an option it pops up at the bottom letting you know that option has been selected.

I can do the list bit and make it so that when you click a item on the list it appears at the bottom saying that item was clicked, I can also do the drop down menu when you click a button. When I put it together however it doesn't work and just crashes. Can someone help me out? Or at least let me know if my code is heading in the right direction? It would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Which part will it crash?

Comment: @LawrenceGimenez, The entire app when I try to access this activity will crash. The parts labelled as errors include the "val listPopupmenu = View(tl+[position])" saying its 'unsupported' and the "this" bit under that saying 'type mismatch'. I hope this answers your question

Comment: I mean what line? Yeah a lot is wrong with this implementation. I suggest creating your own custom Adapter.

Comment: Line 36 and 39 I'm pretty sure. As for the implementation, I'm lost from there onward. I know the code is probably unoptimized and a mess tho.

Comment: I can't tell which one is line 36 or 39.

Comment: @LawrenceGimenez "val listPopupmenu = View(tl+[position])

                val showPopUp = PopupMenu(
                    this,
                    listPopupmenu
                )" this bit